# ObjectGears does not save change in the report filter

Tags: objectgears

I am trying to change the filter in the report definition (Pie chart), the app pops up a message about saving the report, but when I reload the report there is still the old filter. It looks like a bug to me. Or can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a bug in changing the filter in the report as you are describing. What you need to do is:

1. Take out the filter completely and save the report.
2. Reload the report record. There will be know filter.
3. Define your new filter and save the report.
4. Reload the report record. There will be the new filter.